# Rename all files's name in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

```
# -*- coding:utf-8-*-

import os
import time
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("version", help="Enter your package version")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    rootdir = os.getcwd()
    list = os.listdir(rootdir)

    #default version = 1.1.0
    version = '1.1.0'
    if args.version:
        version = args.version

    for line in list:
        times = time.strftime("%Y%m%d",time.localtime())
        list = ['ABCD', 'android', version, 'abcd', times]
        st = '_'
        result = st.join(list) + '.apk'

        origin_file = os.path.join(rootdir, line)
        print(origin_file)
        new_file = os.path.join(rootdir, result)
        print(new_file)
        os.rename(origin_file, new_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Trying to rename all the file to a specific name in the directory after the script.

However, errors here:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "rename-apk.py", line 31, in
>
> os.rename(origin_file, new_file)
>
> OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory

[image]

Comment: What is the print for `origin_file` and `new_file` when the error occurs?

Comment: @AnandSKumar `/Users/Wongzigii/Desktop/rename-py/.idea` and 
`/Users/Wongzigii/Desktop/rename-py/ABCD_android_1.1.22_abcd_20150903.apk`

Comment: What is the value of `os.path.isfile(origin_file)`?

Comment: Try taking the `.` in front of `idea` away and see what happens.

Comment: The strange point is I do not have a file named `.idea` in my directory. How could it come out?

Comment: Interesting.. you posted your `origin_file` in the comments with a trailing `.idea`. what was it supposed to be?

Comment: My directory do not contains `.idea` file. There are only a lot of `apk` files which I would like to rename.

Comment: @Wongzigii On windows, directories beginning with `.` are hidden by default, so it is actually there, you just can't see it. You can change this by going to the folder menu `Tools->Folder options...->View (tab)` and unchecking *Hide protected operating system files*

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, I am using Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using Pycharm , `.idea` folder is as [per documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html) -

> **Project Settings**
>
> Project settings are stored with each specific project as **a set of xml files under the .idea folder**. If you specify the default project settings, these settings will be automatically used for each newly created project.

(Emphasis mine)

Files/Folders with `.` in the beginning of the name are by default hidden.

In any way , the `.idea` folder is not the issue. The issue would also occur if you tried to rename any other directory.

The issue mainly occurs because of how you create the file name, the `times` you use would be constant throughout the execution of the program , since you are only taking the year, month and day.

So basically, you are creating the exact same result name for every file in the list.

The error you got is because you renamed something else to - `ABCD_android_1.1.22_abcd_20150903.apk` , which was a file.

Then you are trying to rename `.idea` (which is a directory) to `ABCD_android_1.1.22_abcd_20150903.apk` which is originally a file , since this is not possible, you get the error - `Not a Directory` .

And you may have even lost of alot of `.apk` , because of how [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) works -

> Rename the file or directory src to dst. If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised. On Unix, if dst exists and is a file, **it will be replaced silently if the user has permission.**

(Emphasis mine)

You should somehow create unique file_names for each `.apk` . Maybe you can include the original filename in the new filename as well , or you should take the timestamp upto the microsecond (You can use datetime module for that, and `%f` format for microsecond in it) (even then if the computer is running too fast, you may run into this issue or get errors) .

Also, you may not want to replace all the files, if so you should consider adding some condition to check which files to replace. For example, if you only want to rename `.apk` files , you can add a condition like -

```
if line.endswith('.apk'):
```

as the first line inside for loop, and the rest of the code inside this if block.

Also, you may not want to use `list` as a variable name, since that shadows the built-in function `list()` . And you should not re-use same variable names like you are doing right now with `list` .

Comment: Should I delete `.idea` folder or do something?

Comment: No, do not delete that folder, you should change how you are naming your files first, and then you can add a condition like `if line.endswith('.apk')` to only replace `.apk` files, if thats what you want.

Comment: Thanks so much. Cheers.